# Set Rails date format for view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

What's the most efficient way to display a date in a view in `dd/mm/yyyy` format?

I modified `config/initializers/date_time.rb` as such:

```
# Date
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y"
```

However, I have a dropdown list that contains dates, and I use that to pass a date parameter  `date_id` for searching purpose. If I use the above line, it doesn't return any results when it should.

My code:

balances_controller.rb

```
  def statement
    @dates = Balance.select("distinct(date)").order('date desc')

    if (params[:date_id].blank?)
      @latestDate = Balance.order('date desc').first.date
    else
      @latestDate = params[:date_id]
    end

    @summaryBalances = Balance.joins(:account).order('accounts.credit').where('date = :abc', {abc: @latestDate})
  end
```

statement.html.erb

```
<h1>Statement at <%= @latestDate %></h1>

<%= form_tag("/statement", method: "get") do %>
<%= select_tag "date_id", options_for_select( @dates.collect {|d| [ d.date, d.date ] }) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @summaryBalances.each do |balance| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= balance.account.name %></td>
        <td class='account-balance'><%= number_to_currency(balance.balance, unit: "£") %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_balance_path(balance) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

html output:

```
<form action="/statement" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<select name="date_id" id="date_id"><option value="2015-11-30">30/11/2015</option>
<option value="2015-10-31">31/10/2015</option>
<option value="2015-09-30">30/09/2015</option></select>
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of resolving this but I've managed to do what I need it to do by creating two separate helper methods. One to display the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and one to return the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format for the parameter.

```
  def date_format(date)
     date.to_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  end
  def date_format2(date)
     date.to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  end
```

Updated statement.html.erb

```
....
<%= form_tag("/statement", method: "get") do %>
<%= select_tag "date_id", options_for_select( @dates.collect {|d| [ date_format(d.date), date_format2(d.date) ] }) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
....
```

Comment: Do you need to take time zone into account?

Comment: @Austio Eventually yes.

Comment: How are you getting the Id of the date?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the actual HTML output for the dropdown list?

Comment: @Austio, I'm not. I'm returning the date.

Comment: @Beartech, I've updated the OP. I've managed to resolve my issue though I'm not sure if it's the most efficient method.

Comment: For future reference, by posting HTML output I meant the actual HTML code generated from your .html.erb code. Also can you show how you are using the new helper methods? There's nothing wrong with using the helper methods to do that, though there might be a way that requires less code. You might take the time to better explain what's going on with your own solution so that others searching might find it useful, and you might get a more efficient answer from someone.